# draw a line from one circle to another in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I will explain the problem that I have in my real project. I am consuming a web service and this returns me n points x, y. I'm simulating the web service with a settimeout. I want to put a circle in those coordinates and for each circle I want to draw a line that connects them. like this:

[image]

I would like to add a line between the circles but showing an animation. like this:

http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326

for example this animation, but point by point

when I run my application I want the line to have an animation from the initial circle to the end. and if I add a new circle I want a line to be created and have an animation to the circle. How can I do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/2rv0o8da/

```
  var svg = d3.select('svg');

  var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40];
  function display(data){
  var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr({
          r:function(d){ return d },
          cx:function(d, i){ return i * 100 + 50 },
          cy:50,
          fill: 'red'
      });
  } 
  display(dataSet);


  setTimeout(function(){
    display([5]);
  },2000)
```

Comment: You have 2 questions here, I'd advise you to pick only one. Also, regarding your dataset: do the circles always have the same y position? Because the dataset is just an array of values for the x position.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado in my real problem if I have 2 x and y positions. for this case it does not matter that they have the same "y". the question is how connect a line between circles with animation.

Comment: Ok, then. I'll answer it.

Comment: thanks man! do you understand me? First I need animate the line in all the circles, later with a settimeout I simulate the service web to add other circle with the same animation..

Comment: Mmm, In that case I'm out. I was about to show you how to animate the line, not how to add more points to it. As I said, this is **two** questions. Here at S.O. I particularly don't like answering questions that ask more than one problem at a time.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado okay no problem. Then help me solve the first problem. create an animation of a line between the circles wih animation. maybe with whatever you do, I can defend myself for the next step. if I am not able to the next step, I will create a new question. do you think it's OK?

Comment: Just posted it. I recommend you post **another** question asking how to add points at the end of the path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering how to connect the dots:

For creating the path that connect your circles, you just have to create a *line generator* which uses the same data.

For instance, this will create an array with 10 objects, each one having a `x` and a `y` position:

```
var dataSet = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
    return {x: someValue, y: someValue}
});
```

So, since we use those properties to position the circles, we just use the same properties in the line generator:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {return d.x})
    .y(function(d) {return d.y})
    .interpolate("monotone")
```

Then, use the function in the bl.ocks you linked:

```
var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var backLayer = svg.append("g");
var frontLayer = svg.append("g");

var dataSet = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: d * 30 + 10,
    y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
  }
});

var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .interpolate("monotone")

function displayCircles(data) {
  var circle = frontLayer.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr({
      r: 6,
      cx: function(d) {
        return d.x
      },
      cy: function(d) {
        return d.y
      },
      fill: 'white',
      stroke: "black",
      "stroke-width": "3px"
    });
};

function displayLine(data) {
  var line = backLayer.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr({
      d: lineGenerator(data),
      fill: 'none',
      stroke: "red",
      "stroke-width": "3px",
      "shape-rendering": "geometricPrecision"
    });

  var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

  line.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
}

displayCircles(dataSet);

setTimeout(function() {
  displayLine(dataSet)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [demo code](http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326) show us a very smart way to animate path and I will give another different solution using [attrTween](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#attrTween):

```
var w = 500, h = 100;
var data = d3.range(100).map(function(d){
    return Math.random() * 5 + 5;
});
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range([0, 500]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 100]);
var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("cardinal")
      .x(function(d,i) {return x(i);})
      .y(function(d) {return y(d);})

var svg = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({ width: w, height: h })
    .style("border", "1px solid #ccc")
    .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr({
        d: line(data.slice(0,1)),
        fill: "none",
        stroke: "#CB6154",
        "stroke-width": 2
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d){
        var f = d3.interpolate(0,50);
        return function(t){
            return line(d.slice(0, Math.ceil(f(t))));
        };
    })
```

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcumuuxo/) results.